# Record the duration of a touch, then print it after

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do you record the duration of a touch and print it after on screen?

[image]

Here is the code above:

```
// add this ivar to your view controller
NSTimeInterval lastTouch;
int textTime;

// assign the time interval in touchesBegan:
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    lastTouch = [event timestamp];
}


// calculate and print interval in touchesEnded:
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    NSTimeInterval touchBeginEndInterval = [event timestamp] - lastTouch;
    textTime = touchBeginEndInterval;
    NSLog(@"touchBeginEndInterval %f", touchBeginEndInterval);
    dynLabel.text = textTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dynLabel.text = textTime;
```

A label's `text` property expects a `NSString*`, but you're giving it a `NSTimeInterval` I.e. a number. That's what the error means. Create a string using e.g. NSString's `-stringWithFormat:` method.

Comment: K, I got it thanks. dynLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", touchBeginEndInterval];